# Impact of changing existing c# class properties from long to List<long>

Tags: linq

I have existing with four properties and getting change in one of the fields from long to `List<long>`.
There is an existing code which is using already long. If I change it to `List<long>` I am unable to modify the existing code. Please help me out.

**before change:**

```
public class Class1
{

    public long prop1 { get; set; }


    public long prop2 { get; set; }


    public List<string> prop3 { get; set; }


    public List<string> prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

**Chnaged class with prop2**

```
public class Class1
{

    public long prop1 { get; set; }


    public **List<long>** prop2 { get; set; }


    public List<string> prop3 { get; set; }


    public List<string> prop3 { get; set; }
}



  var details = Data1
            .Where(m => m.MemberKey == clientMemberId).FirstOrDefault();

         var getdata =Data2
            .Where(x => Data1.prop2.Contains(x.prop2))
            .Select(x => new
            {
                prop1= x.prop1,
                prop3 = x.prop3
            })
            .ToList();
```

> Getting an error at x.prop2

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide what you want this line to do:

```
.Where(x => Data1.prop2.Contains(x.prop2))
```

If you want `Data1.prop2` to contain *any* of the elements from `x.prop2`:

```
.Where(x => Data1.prop2.ToHashSet().IsSupersetOf(x.prop2))
```

If you want `Data1.prop2` to contain *all* of the elements from `x.prop2`:

```
.Where(x => Data1.prop2.ToHashSet().IsSubsetOf(x.prop2))
```

If you want `Data1.prop2` to contain *exactly the same* elements from `x.prop2`:

```
.Where(x => Data1.prop2.ToHashSet().SetEquals(x.prop2))
```

And if you want `Data1.prop2` to contain *exactly the same* elements from `x.prop2` in *exactly the same order*:

```
.Where(x => Data1.prop2.SequenceEqual(x.prop2))
```

Comment: .Where(x => Data1.prop2.Contains(x.prop2)) I need to pick this, because I need to validate Data1.Prop2 contains any of the value in x.Prop2. Here, data1.prop2 and x.prop2 both are list<int>. so it is showing me the error as "Cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.List<long> to long"

Comment: @bmdprasad Well you can't pick that because `Contains` is expecting a single value. Read my answer and see which is most appropriate. It sounds like the first solution.

Comment: If contains not suitable to pick then none of your options are suitable for me, because  Data1.Prop2 is not getting the option Data1.Prop2.ToHashSet() as this is List<long>

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tohashset